# Can I have <SCRIPT> tag inside <TABLE>?

Tags: javascript, html, doctype, script-tag

I got to have a  tag inside a table because PHP writes a code there that adds stuff to an earlier created Javascript array. However, I get a validation error (4.01 strict).

Is there any way I can do this or is it simply forbidden to keep a script like this:

```
<TABLE>
    <TR>
      <SCRIPT></SCRIPT>
        <TD>
        </TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

(is this better maybe?):

```
<TABLE>
    <TR>
        <TD>
         <SCRIPT></SCRIPT>
        </TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Change doctype? What do you think?

Comment: I think you should go to XHTML at least. HTML 4 is so IE6.

Comment: @leppie With XHTML you shouldn't really have inline script blocks at all.  If you're going to have inline scripts all over the place then pretending your HTML is XML is just going to lead to extra problems.

Comment: @leppie: also XHTML is a dying standard; HTML5 is the future.

Comment: I have loads of intrinsic events so then XML won't be for me yet

Comment: @Andreas Bonini: The finalization date of HTML 5 is 2018, I can wait.

Comment: @robertc: I was not providing a solution, only a suggestion.

Comment: @leppie I never suggested you were, I was just pointing out your suggestion is impractical in this case without a completely different approach.  As for the finalization date of HTML5, that's irrelevant, you don't need to wait - you know that CSS2.1 isn't finalised yet?  Have you been using CSS2.1 at all in the meantime?

Comment: @robertc: Actually not directly, I havent done any web dev in the last 2 years  ;P

Comment: HTML4, 5, or XHTML, please lower-case all of your tags.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ever since the release of HTML 5, it *is* legal to have a `<script>` inside most kinds of table element, including `tr`s.

At https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html, you can see that the content models for [`table`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-table-element), [`caption`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-caption-element), [`tbody`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-tbody-element), [`thead`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-thead-element), [`tfoot`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-tfoot-element), [`tr`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-tr-element), [`td`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-td-element) and [`th`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-th-element) all include either *"Flow content"* or *"one or more script-supporting elements"*. At https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#flow-content-2 and https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#script-supporting-elements-2 respectively, we see that `script`s are defined to be both flow content and script-supporting elements, and are therefore allowed within any of those elements.

The notable exceptions are [`colgroup`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-colgroup-element)s (which can only contain `col`s and `template`s) and [`col`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-col-element)s (which can't have content). You can't put a `script` inside either of those.

This means that the asker's example HTML with a script inside a `tr`...

```
<TABLE>
    <TR>
      <SCRIPT></SCRIPT>
        <TD>
        </TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

... is now valid, which you can confirm at https://html5.validator.nu.

[Gumbo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3658298/1709587), stating that `script`s are allowed inside `td`s but not `tr`s, was correct for HTML 4, but is now outdated.

Answer (score 41):

[`SCRIPT`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT) is not allowed in [`TR`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-TR) as the content model of `TR` is defined as `(TH|TD)+`:

```
<!ELEMENT TR       - O (TH|TD)+        -- table row -->
```

That means one or more elements of `TH` or `TD`.

But `SCRIPT` is allowed in `TD`. See the [definition of `TD`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-TD):

```
<!ELEMENT (TH|TD)  - O (%flow;)*       -- table header cell, table data cell-->
```

Where the [parameter entity *flow*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#flow) is defined as:

```
<!ENTITY % flow "%block; | %inline;">
```

And [*inline*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#inline) is defined as:

```
<!ENTITY % inline "#PCDATA | %fontstyle; | %phrase; | %special; | %formctrl;">
```

And [*special*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#special) is define as:

```
<!ENTITY % special
   "A | IMG | OBJECT | BR | SCRIPT | MAP | Q | SUB | SUP | SPAN | BDO">
```

Comment: This answer is outdated; `script`s inside `tr`s are legal as of HTML 5. I've posted my own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53451056/1709587).