# Where can I put a script tag?

Tags: javascript, html

Where is it legal to put a `<script>` tag in html?

I have a legitimate (I swear!) reason to use `document.write` in parts of my page. This means I need to put

```
<script>document.write('some goodness')</script>
```

at some arbitrary point in the DOM. Is that always supported?

Comment: There is no legitimate non-development use for `document.write`.

Comment: Just before the closing body tag, according to this related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup?rq=1

Comment: Guys, I'm asking where is is *allowed*, not where you'd think it best to put it.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup?rq=1

Comment: @Neal, no that's not a duplicate. This one is explicitly about `document.write`, which makes a *huge* difference in script location.

Comment: Not a duplicate since this asks about legal places, not optimal place.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, [I can think of at least one legitimate use of `document.write`](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/139372/referencing-external-javascript-vs-hosting-my-own-copy/139380#139380).

Comment: The answer depends on HTML version. A complete answer would for this and other reasons (like the rather messy syntax of HTML5 in this respect) be rather large. It is questionable whether it would be useful. You should probably ask whether some particular place is valid or what the best place is, in a particular situation that you should describe.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, is that conjecture or is that based on hard evidence? I find that usually early, early features that stabilized back in the Netscape Navigator days tend to be left exactly the same, for fear of breaking stuff, unless they get officially deprecated.

Comment: @chowey, what are you asking about? I stated that this depends on HTML version. Do you seriously doubt that?

Comment: Okay, so you are conjecturing because it is pretty obvious that things change on HTML version. I'll agree with that. It's just not a useful comment.

Comment: @chowey, it is not a conjecture, it is a basic fact of the situation and directly affects how the question should be answered, if the question were taken as asked. From your comments, it seems that you are actually interested in browser behavior, which is something completely different. This is yet another reason to close the question. Try asking about a real problem you are facing.

Comment: @zzzzBov Would be "better" as `document.createElement('script')`...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, how so? What would making it more verbose do for the script other than add additional unnecessary bytes and increasing the risk of adding the script to the wrong place in the document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[In HTML5 the `<script>` element is defined as being allowed in the following places:](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-script-element)

> #### Contexts in which this element can be used:
>
> - Where metadata content is expected.
> - Where phrasing content is expected.
> - Where script-supporting elements are expected.

Most content elements allow for `phrasing content`, and the `<head>` element allows for `metadata content`.

There are *some* elements that **do not** support the `<script>` element as direct descendants , and it should be noted that this list is subject to change, so consult the spec, as this is probably not a comprehensive list:

- `<html>`
- `<title>`
- `<script>`

Additionally, you shouldn't put a `<script>` element in a `<noscript>` element because it simply doesn't make any sense to do so, even though it would technically be supported by the specification.

Comment: I love this answer. But in my experience, putting a `<script>` tag as a direct child to the `<html>` element *does* work. I guess that is just due to browser quirks?

Comment: The answer cites a mutable working draft without saying it. It only applies to one work-in-progress version of HTML. And e.g. `<html>` surely “supports” the `<script>` element – it just does not allow it as a child.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, I can never keep the HTML5 spec links straight, [is this a better reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#the-script-element), or do you have a different HTML5 spec in mind?

Answer (score 3):

You can include them wherever you want between your `<head>` or `<body>` tags :

- If you insert it in the head, it'll be loaded before the page rendering,
- If you place it on the body, it will be loaded once all the page is
  rendered, so the user won't wait for your script to be parsed before
  the pages renders = **faster page rendering**.

Exceptions :

- Inside a `<title>` tag (as you said)
- <strike>Inside a `<tr>` ([see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3658298/1437016))</strike> Apparently it does (see after)

I tried with a few elements on that [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bigood/w8Z87/), you can try it

Comment: Apparently it doesn't work in the `<title>` tag, for example, so it is  *not* legal everywhere.

Comment: @chowey Thanks for the tip, I never tried that!